# Not getting Order Confirmation Emails but I get the "Welcome, Allysin!" Email after registering while placing an order

Tags: order-email, order-confirmation

```
Magento 1.9.3.7 out of the box
Porto theme
```

I did a new Magento install. I put the Porto theme in, added categories and products and put in all the relevant info.

Now, when placing a test order - I never receive the Order Confirmation Email (I tried with 2 different Email addresses and checked the Spam folders).

What's interesting is - when going through and placing an order, I register for an account and t**hen get the Welcome Email titled: Welcome, Allysin!** *with the message that looks like this*:

---

```
Welcome to MYSITE.

To log in when visiting our site just click Login or My Account at the top of every page, and then enter your email address and password.
Use the following values when prompted to log in:
Email: myEMAILaddress
Password: myPASSWORD
When you log in to your account, you will be able to do the following:
Proceed through checkout faster when making a purchase
Check the status of orders
View past orders
Make changes to your account information
Change your password
Store alternative addresses (for shipping to multiple family members and friends!)
If you have any questions, please feel free to contact us at support@example.com .

Thank you, MYSITE!
```

---

**Why would I not receive the Order Confirmation Emails if I get these Welcome Emails?**

Comment: I am facing the same issue in my magento 2.2 site. Can you please elaborate on what you did exactly to solve it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution for me was to add the following into the cron.php file:**

```
 isShellDisabled = true;
```